# Ejabberdctl command not found error returned

Tags: ejabberd

I have installed the ejabberd with run package `ejabberd-23.01-1-linux-x64.run` on ec2 instance. The status is showing active however the commands to create new user is not working. Following command returns error mentioned below

```
sudo ejabberdctl register admin bkstg adm1nbkstg@#2023

sudo: ejabberdctl: command not found
```

Not sure what is the issue here, it worked properly on the local though. Please help to get it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

When you installed it, check the path it was installed in.

If it was installed in `$HOME/opt/ejabberd-23.01`, then the script is available in `$HOME/opt/ejabberd-23.01/bin/ejabberdctl`

> Not sure what is the issue here, it worked properly on the local though.

Maybe when you installed in your local machine, you had root privileges and it got installed in the system, instead of your $HOME ? Or maybe there's another ejabberdctl from a previous installation in your local machine...